# Combine MySQL Queries into table

Tags: mysql

I have a table I have tried to make as efficient as I can, to allow for a single entry for each data point in the table, and link the type of entry to another table, and the location to a third table.

This essentially means in a sensor table, I define the location of the sensor and the sensorID, in a test table i define the tests that can be run, the testID, the units, the name of the test and the upper and lower limit and in the final table (the data table) i reference the entryID, the current DATETIME, the sensorID, the testID and the test value.

This means the table has lots of individual records for each sensor and test but these may occur at the same time, for example one sensor may output up to 4 tests at the same time.

I use a SELECT like the below to get the basic information;

```
SELECT raw_data.entry_date, sensorid.desk as location, tests.testname as test, raw_data.test_value as testresult 
FROM raw_data 
INNER JOIN sensorID ON raw_data.sensorID = SensorID.Sensor 
INNER JOIN tests ON raw_data.test_id = tests.testid 
ORDER BY entry_date ASC
```

This works well to get each entry, or filter by test but it works horribly if I am trying to group all results by time and date. Is there a way I can make a dynamic MySQL result which presents as more of a column based system e.g.

DATE | SENSOR | TEST A from (tests.testname)| TEST B ... | TEST C ... | TEST D ...

The idea with this would be that in the column for TEST A it would present the results for TEST A, and so on.

I would be filtering, so would not query the entire database but rather a specific sensor/site etc, but the main thing is how to dynamically do it so I don't need to change all the column names and everything each time?

Ultimatally I want to be able to take this to feed into JSON, but I need to group by DATE and Location, and present the test names across the columns, and the row values being the test_value for each test name.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a basic pivot query here:

```
SELECT
    r.entry_date,
    s.desk AS location,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.testname = 'A' THEN r.test_value END) AS test_A,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.testname = 'B' THEN r.test_value END) AS test_B,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.testname = 'C' THEN r.test_value END) AS test_C
FROM raw_data r
INNER JOIN sensorID s
    ON r.sensorID = s.Sensor 
INNER JOIN tests t
    ON r.test_id = t.testid 
GROUP BY
    r.entry_date,
    s.desk
ORDER BY
    r.entry_date;
```

Comment: is there a way to have the MAX(Case ...) to be dynamic, ideally id love to have the query within PHP and not need to change the tests, but this appears to require the tests to be hardcoded, could I somehow pull the test names out of a query (e.g. SELECT DISTINCT testname FROM t) and feed that into the pivot query? -- Many Thanks!

Comment: @user1829564 You would need dynamic SQL for that, and I have no experience with dynamic SQL in PHP.